# pgrep 3.2.8 number of running processes

Tags: bash, grep

Using `pgrep 3.3.10`, if I want to know the number of processing running with commands which match the string `pippo` I can do `watch -n 1 'pgrep -c pippo'`. With `pgrep 3.2.8` it doesn't work, it gives me:

`pgrep: invalid option -- 'c' Usage: pgrep [-flvx] [-d DELIM] [-n|-o] [-P PPIDLIST] [-g PGRPLIST] [-s SIDLIST] [-u EUIDLIST] [-U UIDLIST] [-G GIDLIST] [-t TERMLIST] [PATTERN]`

Is there an equivalent way of giving me a continuously updating number of commands matching a string in `pgrep 3.2.8`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe it to `wc -l`:

```
watch -n 1 'pgrep pippo | wc -l'
```